# protecting data with .htaccess, 2 servers and a cross-domain conection

Tags: cross-domain

I was trying to deny the access to my json files through internet because I want that my users get these files over my website and not by absolute URL in the explorer.

After many hours surfing over internet trying to find a solution, I read a lot of comments that were talking about cross-domain petitions.
Supposing we have 2 domains with 2 different ip's I protect the first server with all the json data by using an .htaccess that only allows the ip of the domain which is gonna request the json.
Then in my second domain I would do a async petition so I could get the data.

So my question is, if the second domain uses my IP or its IP address to request the first server the file and in case if it's possible to do what i've purposed in that way.

For the moment that's what I've done:

SERVER-1

.htaccess

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 106.211.22.0/20
```

SERVER-2

```
<html>
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/1.7.2.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://server1.es/json/list.json',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var value = responseData.someKey;
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('POST failed.');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

USER-IP using the domain 2

211.122.220.125